# Selecting elements from an array based on another array values in python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, knn

consedering the array under (data) is a collection of 5 documents and y_data is the documents labels(class 0 and class 1):

```
data=[[0,0,5,0,7],[1,5,0,3,0],[1,4,7,9,2],[3,5,9,3,0],[4,8,0,1,4]]
y_data=[0,0,1,0,1]
data=np.array(data)
y_data=np.array(y_data)

#calculating euclidean_distance between two documents
from math import sqrt
def euclidean_distance(doc1, doc2):
    distance = 0.0
    for i in range(len(doc1)):
          distance += (doc1[i] - doc2[i])**2
    return sqrt(distance)

from operator import itemgetter

# calculating distances between a document and other documents and sorted them
def get_dist(train, test_row,y_train):
    distances = list()
    dist_ord=list()   
    for i in range(len(train)):
        dist = euclidean_distance(test_row, train[i])
        distances.append((train[i],y_train[i], dist))
    #sorted by classes then by distance
    distances.sort(key=itemgetter(1,2))
    #just keeping dist 
    for i in distances:
      dist_ord.append(i[2])
    return dist_ord,distances

dist_ord,distances = get_dist(data, data[1],y_data)
print(dist_ord)
print(distances)
```

I wrote the code above to calculate the euclidean_distance between a document(document 1) and the other 5 documents,I sorted the distances based on the document class then I sorted distances for each class from the closest to the farest,I got this results:

```
[(array([1, 5, 0, 3, 0]), 0, 0.0), (array([3, 5, 9, 3, 0]), 0, 9distances=[9.219544457292887), (array([0, 0, 5, 0, 7]), 0, 10.44030650891055), (array([4, 8, 0, 1, 4]), 1, 6.164414002968976), (array([1, 4, 7, 9, 2]), 1, 9.486832980505138)]
```

I just need distances so the final result is:

```
[0.0, 9.219544457292887, 10.44030650891055, 6.164414002968976, 9.486832980505138]
```

Now I need to select the k nearest distances for each class and I also need to remove distance=0 (the distance between a document and itself)
I wrote the code under to solve this problem(for  k=1):

```
class_neighbors=list()
n=list()
all_c_neighbors=list()
classes=np.unique(y_data)
for c in range(len(classes)):
    for i in range(len(distances)):
        if distances[i][1]==c and distances[i][2]!=0:
           n.append(distances[i][2])
    k=1 
    class_neighbors=n[:k]
all_c_neighbors.extend(class_neighbors)
print(all_c_neighbors)
```

the problem is I got the nearest neighbor just for the class 0 :

```
[9.219544457292887]
```

the right answer should be like this:

```
[9.219544457292887,6.164414002968976]
```

can any one correct my last code to get the right answer?

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: it's my first question on stackoverflow,am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: ok,I will edit my question and I will put my own code to solve the problem.thank you!

Comment: Can any one help me please?!

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
distances = [(array([1, 5, 0, 3, 0]), 0, 0.0),
 (array([3, 5, 9, 3, 0]), 0, 9.219544457292887),
 (array([0, 0, 5, 0, 7]), 0, 10.44030650891055),
 (array([4, 8, 0, 1, 4]), 1, 6.164414002968976),
 (array([1, 4, 7, 9, 2]), 1, 9.486832980505138)]
```

In this array, each element has three items: the xdata, the class, and the distance.

First, `groupby` the class

```
import itertools

grouped_distances = {k: list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(distances, key=lambda item: item[1])}
```

This groups by the `item[1]` for each `item` in `distances`. Then, it creates a dictionary whose keys are the class labels and values are lists containing each element of `distances` that has that class label.

which gives

```
{0: [(array([1, 5, 0, 3, 0]), 0, 0.0),
  (array([3, 5, 9, 3, 0]), 0, 9.219544457292887),
  (array([0, 0, 5, 0, 7]), 0, 10.44030650891055)],
 1: [(array([4, 8, 0, 1, 4]), 1, 6.164414002968976),
  (array([1, 4, 7, 9, 2]), 1, 9.486832980505138)]}
```

Now we can go through every class label in the dictionary, extract the distances we care about, and select the first `k` distances after sorting them

```
# We want the k nearest distances
k = 1
all_class_distances = []
for class_name, class_items in grouped_distances.items():
    # Extract the distances from class_items and sort them, excluding zeros
    distances = sorted([item[2] for item in class_items if item[2] != 0])
    # Select the first k
    all_class_distances.extend(distances[:k])
```

Now, `all_class_distances` is:

```
[9.219544457292887, 6.164414002968976]
```